# Entity Framework Very Slow

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have thousands of contacts in just one group (contacts and groups have a many-to-many relationship) :

```
public class Group
{
    public int GroupID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
}

public class Contact
{
    public int ContactID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Group> Groups { get; set; }
}
```

When I fetch all the contacts, it takes half a second. No problem :

```
context.Contacts.ToList();
```

I tried this and it took again less than a second :

```
 db.Contacts.SelectMany(s => s.Groups.Where(c => c.GroupID == 1)).ToList();
```

However, this took 15 seconds to load (it hangs on the second line) :

```
var groups = context.Groups.Include(x => x.Contacts);
foreach(var group in groups)
{
     foreach(var contact in group.Contacts)
     {
         contactsInGroup.Add(contact);
     }
}
```

Same problem here (it hangs on the fourth line) :

```
var groups = context.Groups.ToList();
foreach(var group in groups)
{
     db.Entry(group).Collection(p => p.Contacts).Load(); 

     foreach(var contact in group.Contacts)
     {
         contactsInGroup.Add(contact);
     }
}
```

Anybody understand why  ?

Comment: Which EF version do you use? Use EF 6.1 and ngen the EF dll this improves speed a lot.

Comment: What kind of performance do you get when you do `context.Contacts.SelectMany(a=> a.Groups).ToList();`?

Comment: Sounds like a [Cartesian Product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) problem.  How many records are return in those 15 seconds (number of Contacts, and numer of Groups)?

Comment: EF performs very poorly when you `Include()` navigation properties which are collections, with queries that return a lot of duplicate information that EF throws out before returning to you. Very wasteful!

Comment: I have EF6.1. With the SelectMany it's less than a second. I have around 10 000 contacts in just one group (it can't be a cartesian product problem). @CoryNelson Any solutions ?

Comment: Do you have an index on the *second* column in the many-to-many link table for `Groups` and `Contacts`, especially if the second column is the `GroupID`? Did you test the performance when running the corresponding SQL with a database tool (for instance SQL Server Management Studio)?

Comment: No I don't have an index. And I've just tested with an SQL profiler, the corresponding SQL takes less than a second. I guess it's something inside or with Entity Framework.

Answer (score 0):

**Include()** and **Load()** both to load related entities **EagerLoading** or **LazyLoading** respectively.

I think you can improve your performance to add index in your model

```
public class Group
{
 [Index("GroupIdIndex", 1)]
 public int GroupID { get; set; }
 public string Name { get; set; }

 public virtual ICollection<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
}

public class Contact
{
 [Index("ContactIdIndex", 1)]
 public int ContactID { get; set; }
 public string FirstName { get; set; }
 public string LastName { get; set; }

 public virtual ICollection<Group> Groups { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I still have the exact problem. I checked with an SQL profiler and in all cases, it takes less than a second to execute the SQL. But for some reason it still takes 15 seconds in debug with include() or load(). It seems to be something with C# or Entity Framework but not with the SQL query.